# Java DateFormat format and parse gives unexpected result

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm getting unexpected output when running following code,

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
Date date = df.parse("2012-06-23");
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Output : 2012-01-01

I'm expecting 2012-06-23 as output,what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: dude.......RTFM, all the information you need is right in the javadocs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yyyy should be all lowercase, try that and see if it makes a difference...

Answer (score 3):

Refer this [Date & time in Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm). You'll get the date format used

Use 'y' instead of 'Y'.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = df.parse("2012-06-23");
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```