# DateFormat in java giving unexpected result

Tags: java, date-format

I have created a DateFormat object in java

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

then created a Date object

```
Date d = formatter.parse("2015-03-23 11:59:59");
```

but the value of d that i am getting is "Fri Jan 23 11:59:59 IST 2015", but it should be "Mon Mar 23 11:59:59 IST 2015"

Can somebody please explain why i am getting this result. I have already checked explanation in 
[Java DateFormat format and parse gives unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162404/java-dateformat-format-and-parse-gives-unexpected-result) but i have specified yyyy in smaller case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is incorrect.

You should use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` instead of  `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`.

We use `MM` for month while `mm` for minutes in `Java` [simpelDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
M   Month in year 
m   Minute in hour
```